# What is causing the issue here?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

when I run this code in ruby:

```
updated_users = []
users = [{:name => "sam" , :number => 001 }]
ids = ["aa" , "bb" , "cc"]
 
users.each do |user|
  ids.each do |id|
    user[:guid] = id
    updated_users << user
  end       
end

p updated_users
```

I get:

```
[{:name=>"sam", :number=>1, :guid=>"cc"},
 {:name=>"sam", :number=>1, :guid=>"cc"},
 {:name=>"sam", :number=>1, :guid=>"cc"}]
```

I expected to get:

```
[{:name=>"sam", :number=>1, :guid=>"aa"},
 {:name=>"sam", :number=>1, :guid=>"bb"},
 {:name=>"sam", :number=>1, :guid=>"cc"}]
```

What is happening and how should I get the desired output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding Ruby Closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888247/understanding-ruby-closures)

Answer (score 5):

Your question reflects a common misunderstanding held by budding Rubyists. You begin with the following:

```
updated_users = []
users = [{:name => "sam" , :number => 001 }]
ids = ["aa" , "bb" , "cc"]
```

`users` is an array containing a single hash. Let's note the id of that hash object:

```
users.first.object_id
  #=> 1440
```

Now let's execute your code with some `puts` statements added to see what is going on.

```
users.each do |user|
  puts "user = #{user}"
  puts "user.object_id = #{user.object_id}"
  ids.each do |id|
    puts "\nid = #{id}"
    user[:guid] = id
    puts "user = #{user}"
    puts "user.object_id = #{user.object_id}"
    updated_users << user
    puts "updated_users = #{updated_users}"
    updated_users.size.times do |i|
      puts "updated_users[#{i}].object_id = #{updated_users[i].object_id}"
    end
  end
end
```

This displays the following.

```
user = {:name=>"sam", :number=>1}
user.object_id = 1440
```

So far, so good. Now begin the `ids.each` loop:

```
id = aa
user = {:name=>"sam", :number=>1, :guid=>"aa"}
user.object_id = 1440
```

As `user` did not previously have a key `:guid`, the key-value pair `:guid=>"aa"` was added to `user`. Note that `user`'s id has not changed. `user` is then appended to the (empty) array `updated_users`:

```
updated_users = [{:name=>"sam", :number=>1, :guid=>"aa"}]
updated_users[0].object_id = 1440
```

Again this is what we should expect. The next element of `ids` is then processed:

```
id = bb
user = {:name=>"sam", :number=>1, :guid=>"bb"}
user.object_id = 1440
```

Since `user` has a key `:guid` this merely changes the value of that key from `"aa"` to `"bb"`. `user` is then appended to `updated_users`:

```
updated_users = [{:name=>"sam", :number=>1, :guid=>"bb"},
                 {:name=>"sam", :number=>1, :guid=>"bb"}]
updated_users[0].object_id = 1440
updated_users[1].object_id = 1440
```

The first and second elements of this array are seen to be the same object `user`, so changing the value of `:user`'s key `:guid` affected both elements in the same way.

The same thing happens when the third and last element of `ids` is processed:

```
id = cc
user = {:name=>"sam", :number=>1, :guid=>"cc"}
user.object_id = 1440
updated_users = [{:name=>"sam", :number=>1, :guid=>"cc"},
                 {:name=>"sam", :number=>1, :guid=>"cc"},
                 {:name=>"sam", :number=>1, :guid=>"cc"}]
updated_users[0].object_id = 1440
updated_users[1].object_id = 1440
updated_users[2].object_id = 1440
```

Got it?

---

To obtain the result you want you need to append `updated_users` with distinct hashes derived from `user`:

```
users.each do |user|
  ids.each do |id|
    updated_users << user.merge(guid: id)
  end
end

updated_users
  #=> [{:name=>"sam", :number=>1, :guid=>"aa"},
  #    {:name=>"sam", :number=>1, :guid=>"bb"},
  #    {:name=>"sam", :number=>1, :guid=>"cc"}]
```

Note that `users` has not been *mutated* (changed):

```
users
  #=> [{:name=>"sam", :number=>1}]
```

See [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge). Note that `user.merge(guid: id)` is shorthand for `user.merge({ guid: id })` or, equivalently, `user.merge({ :guid => id })`.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to explain this in details. I did a similar tracing and observed that the hash value change is occurring to the hash itself as well as the array containing the same hash, but did not know of the merge method to avoid mutating the hash. Also the object_id is helpful in illustrating what was happening. Thanks!